# How to call an oracle stored proc in apache beam?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am just trying to learn Apache Beam and am returning data from an oracle database. I have managed to set up basic connectivity and return some data but I need to call a stored proc before running the sql query to return my data (the stored proc sets the query context to limit the data returned to a specific partition)

I've tried adding a second .withQuery statement but this does not work. The code doesn't return an error but returns data from all partitions

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<List<String>> rows p.apply(JdbcIO.<List<Strng>>read()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
        "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver","jdbc:oracle:thin:@server")
        .withUsername("uname")
        .withPassword("pword")
        )
    .withQuery("call procname(partitionid)")
    .withQuery("Select * from table")
    .withCoder(ListCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
    .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<List<String>>(){
        public List<String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
            List<String> addRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=1; i<= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++)
            {
                addRow.add(i-1, String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i)));
            }
        return addRow;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I asked in Beam user channel and haven't received any feedback, so I assume this is a missing feature and create this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6525. Contributions will be very welcomed to it. Alternatively, you might can ask in Beam dev channel and see if this JIRA could be prioritized.

Comment: Thanks for responding and raising the  jira, at least I know I haven't missed anything obvious! I'll take a look to see what I can do to contribute

Comment: Are you able to call the stored procedure now ?